# How to compare multiple values in Google sheet in a single row?

Tags: google-sheets

Please check the attached screenshot.

[image]

I want to compare values in "User 1 Values" and "User 2 values" and I want to assign 5 points for each value that is common.

What formula do I write in "Actual Points" to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(SPLIT(B2,", "),SPLIT(C2,", "),0)))*5)
```

SPLIT Both values by "," and MATCH them.